# Combining Lists of elements to List of Tuples

Tags: python

How can I combine a List of elements with a List of Tuples (as shown below) ?

```
a = ['x', 'y', 1234]
b = [('Broad Street', 'NY'), ('Park Street', 'CA')]
```

Expected output:

```
[('x', 'y', 1234, 'Broad Street', 'NY'), ('x', 'y', 1234, 'Park Street',  'CA')]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [extended iterable unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/) to build the tuples of the expected result:

```
res = [(*a, *bi) for bi in b]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[('x', 'y', 1234, 'Broad Street', 'NY'), ('x', 'y', 1234, 'Park Street', 'CA')]
```

As an alternative, use:

```
tuple_a = tuple(a)
res = [tuple_a + bi for bi in b]
```